# Settings for direct connection from one PC to another with WDS enabled

Tags: networking, router, routing, openwrt, wds

I have the following network topology:
[image: Network topology]

The `main` router (installed by provider with proprietary software) connected to the Internet, the `repeater` is WDS bridge in repeater mode with `OpenWRT` and `relayd`.

`PC` has IP `192.168.176.84`

`Workstation` has IP `192.168.176.86`

`repeater` has IP `192.168.176.94`

`main router` has IP `192.168.176.93`

So sometimes `tracert 192.168.176.86` from `PC (192.168.176.84)` is

```
Tracing route to Workstation [192.168.176.86]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  Workstation [192.168.176.86]

Trace complete.
```

and sometimes like

```
Tracing route to Workstation [192.168.176.86]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.176.94
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.176.93
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.176.94
  4    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  Workstation [192.168.176.86]

Trace complete.
```

Why? Does it related to `OpenWRT`, `relayd`, `WDS` or `ARP`? How to fix it and make path from `PC` to `Workstation` as shortest as possible (only through `repeater`) with keeping access to Internet from both and without destroying WDS?

Comment: (The title and diagram refer to WPS, is that a typo?)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yep, it's WDS. Fixed, thank you

Comment: Is your repeater running DHCP service when it should not? Does the PC always report the correct netmask configured (255.255.255.240), especially with the longer traceroute? And, why is `relayd` involved here at all?

Comment: Where are you running the traceroute **from**?

Comment: @user1686 No, DHCP is turned off in repeater. Both PC & and Workstation configured with static IP, but even with DHCP - yes, mask is correct. `relayd` is because my `main` router and `repeater` are from different manufactures (broadcomm & atheros) and WDS is usually incompatible between different manufacturers. But it works with `relayd` as mentioned here: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/relay_configuration

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm running `tracert 192.168.176.86` from my PC (192.168.176.84) on Windows, if it's matter

Comment: I have bad news.  I moved away from OpentWRT due to the absolutely network breaking performance it had on my devices.  Once I moved to a premium commercial router, which has many of the OpenWRT features, my own networking issues I had ceased.  For instance UPnP despite being enabled never worked reliably.  I could be off, it could be the WDS bridge connection, but I would make sure you are running the current version of OpenWRT supported by your device.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm very satisfied with OpenWRT on my router (TP-Link Archer C7 v4) because it drops no more than 10% of speed with WDS while latest stock firmware droped it up to 60% and worked only with 2.4 (yes, I compare 2.4 with 2.4, but the same 10% is when I use 5, which wasn't available with stock at all).

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using latest OpenWrt 22.03.3 r20028-43d71ad93e available for my router

Comment: I'm not sure whether WDS being incompatible is still true 20 years later. The "4-address" frame type that's the core of WDS is actually part of 802.11, last I checked.

Comment: I found what I accidentally wrote Workstation IP address 192.168.176.86 as DNS server for PC. I'll check system status at next few days and will mark question as solved if it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like I accidentally assigned IP address of `Workstation` (destination of tracert) `192.168.176.86` as a `DNS server` for `PC` (tracert source). After I fixed it, it's always

```
Tracing route to Workstation [192.168.176.86]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  Workstation [192.168.176.86]

Trace complete.
```